# iPhone 5c software update just loads?

Tags: ios, software-update

I have an iPhone 5c and works great. The issue is I try to update my iPhone but it will stay at the loading part for a long time and wont load. How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same problem a few days ago. It kept me on the phone with tech support with my internet service for 2 hours, It's a problem with Apple's servers. My advice would be to restart your iPhone frequently and keep trying to update it. Eventually, it work, just keep trying because iOS 9 is worth the extra effort.